# Rsync within expect script: error "No such file or directory"

Tags: expect

I want to execute rsync to update several directories on another machine, without typing the password for each one of them. I decided to try the expect extension by following some simple StackOverflow examples. See below a very simplified version of my script. The rsync command works correctly when executed by itself. However, when I run the script, I get the following output:

```
Remote password: 
spawn rsync -rv /home/john/TestDir/* jim@192.168.0.20:/home/jim/TestDir
(jim@192.168.0.20) Password:
building file list ... 
rsync: [sender] link_stat "/home/john/TestDir/*" failed: No such file or directory (2)
done

sent 17 bytes  received 20 bytes  74.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1338) [sender=3.2.7]
```

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -d
 
read -s -p "Remote password: " PW
echo ""
expect <<EOF
    spawn rsync -rv  /home/john/TestDir/* jim@192.168.0.20:/home/jim/TestDir
    expect "assword:"
    send "$PW\r"
    expect eof
EOF
```

Comment: remove the `*` char.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you enter `/path/*` in the shell, it is the shell that expands this pattern to a list of filenames before passing it as an argument. However, the `spawn` command of `expect` does not do pattern expansion, so rsync receives a literal `*` and a file by that name does not exist.

There are several ways to work around it. One is to change the command to not use pattern expansion. @pynexj suggested removing the `*`, which works, but note that there is a difference between `rsync -r foo/* bar` and `rsync -r foo/ bar`: the latter will also copy hidden files (starting with `.`) while the former will not (because they are not matched by `*`).

However, you said your goal was to copy several directories without having to enter the password for each one. It's likely that a better solution to achieve this is to setup public key authentication, so you don't have to enter any passwords at all.

Here is one tutorial on how to configure this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server

Comment: (1) True, hidden files are not copied with "*".  (2) I don't want to avoid typing the password for other operations.

Answer (score 0):

For Expect <sup>(which uses [tcl](/questions/tagged/tcl))</sup> the `*` char as in `/home/john/TestDir/*` has no special meaning. You can explicitly use a shell to run your command:

```
spawn bash -c "rsync -rv  /home/john/TestDir/* jim@192.168.0.20:/home/jim/TestDir"
#     ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks, iincluding "bash -c" works!  I discovered another problem which must have something to do with TCL. My code doesn't show it but I had to leave one space before the first line "#!/usr/...". Otherwise, it produces a long error message!